# How to put a figure on below paragraph in latex

Tags: floats

I want put figure below the paragraph in Latex (one page) i use winshell but always it's apply the figure   above the paragraph

note: there is enough space to put figure I want to put figure  below the paragraph in one page both figure and paragraph should be in one page but always figure go above how solve this

```
\begin{figure} 

\centering

\includegraphics[width=4in]{image}

\caption[my image ]

{Imy image}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `figure` environment is used to create *floating* figures -- LaTeX feels free to move them around to the best-looking place. As an optional argument to the `figure` environment, you can tell LaTeX where to put the figure. (By default, it goes to the top of a page.)

To have it show up where you've put it in your code, invoke it like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

The `h` stands for "here." You could also specify the bottom of the page by saying `[b]`. You can list more than one preference -- `[hb]` means "put it here, but if there isn't room, put it at the bottom of a page."

Comment: It should be noted that even with `h`, LaTeX can float the figure elsewhere.  There are packages on CTAN that actually do give the option to "unfloat" a float, e.g. the package `here`.  I do not know what the currently best option is, though.

Comment: If you want it to not float, just place the image (either on its own, or in something like a `minipage` and use [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}` to place the caption) and not in a floating environment. The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides a `H` float placement specifier.

Comment: This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[h!]` option to make the figure appear exactly where it is in the text instead of floating to someplace else.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
```

Refer: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_insert_an_image_at_a_specific_point_in_the_document%3F